# ReactiveTest usage to mock an observable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, reactive

I'm a bit confused about the usage of ReactiveTest: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242967%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

I have a method ScanDevices in a class DeviceService that I'd like to test with the ReactiveTest features.
The method takes an IObservable from `bleAdapter.Scan()`.

I'd like to mock this bleAdapter.Scan(), to unit test the behavior of `ScanDevices()` . I try to mock the bleAdapter.Scan() with Moq.

```
 //interface to mock
 public interface IAdapter {
        IObservable<IScanResult> Scan(ScanConfig config = null);
 }

 //class to test
 class DeviceService {
        public IObservable<DeviceModel> ScanDevices()
        {
            return bleAdapter.Scan() // this returns an IObservable
                .Where(IsMatching)
                .Distinct(DistinctByUuid)
                .Select(ToDeviceModel);
        }
}
```

Here is my unit test:

```
       public class DeviceServiceTest: ReactiveTest {
            [TestMethod]
            public void ShouldReceiveOneDevice()
            {
                var mockBleAdapter = new Mock<IAdapter>();
                var deviceInteractionService = new DeviceInteractionService(mockBleAdapter.Object);

                var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
                var obs = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(OnNext(100, new MockScannedDevice())); // create an observable that will emit one value


                mockBleAdapter.Setup(adapter => adapter.Scan(null))
                    .Returns(obs); // use Moq framework to return the observable created

                scheduler.Start();

                deviceInteractionService.ScanDevices()
                        .Subscribe(res => Console.WriteLine("hello"));
            }
   }
```

The "hello" is never printed. I'm doing it wrong...
Do you have any good way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Why your setup for IAdapter  pass null to scan? I do not see that Scan receive any parameter within system under test... One more are you providing also that mocked adapter to your sut through constructor or property?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Regarding null passed to scan, I have to do this otherwise I get an error "an expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments".
Regarding providing of mocked adapter, I've updated my question, to illustrate this.

Comment: Could you please provide IAdapter interface?

Comment: I've added it in the question.

Comment: The usage of Mock is correct (I've used it in other methods), I think my issue is with the usage of ReactiveTest and scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

Argh... the issue was that you need to setup your subscriptions before calling `scheduler.Start()`

So, to get the hello to be printed, here it is:

```
 public class DeviceServiceTest: ReactiveTest {
            [TestMethod]
            public void ShouldReceiveOneDevice()
            {
                var mockBleAdapter = new Mock<IAdapter>();
                var deviceInteractionService = new DeviceInteractionService(mockBleAdapter.Object);

                var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
                var obs = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(OnNext(100, new MockScannedDevice())); // create an observable that will emit one value


                mockBleAdapter.Setup(adapter => adapter.Scan(null))
                    .Returns(obs); // use Moq framework to return the observable created

                // subscribe
                deviceInteractionService.ScanDevices()
                        .Subscribe(res => Console.WriteLine("hello"));

                // then start
                scheduler.Start();

            }
   }
```

Comment: Nice that you have found solution. Btw it is not really convenient to check if something is written to output and also you should structure your tests to follow AAA structure...

Comment: Totally true, this is just a test to try the scheduler.